# DevDemon Forms or Snaptcha outputting "Array" right before snaptcha field

Tags: devdemon-forms, snaptcha

I am using Forms 3.4.13 and Snaptcha 1.7.5.

I just created a single contact form in Forms, and enabled Snaptcha. When outputting my form, I am noticing the the word "Array" is getting added to my form.

It's showing up right after the `<div class="hiddenfields"></div>` and right before the `<div class="snap" ...>`

If I disable Snaptcha in my form, it goes away.

I prepended and appended some test text to the $field value in line 91 of `ext.snaptcha.php` to see if the "Array" text was part of that, but it wasn't, it came before that.

UPDATE:
I dug deeper and found where the word "Array" is getting added.

On line 730 of `mod.forms.php`

`$OUT_FORM_PREPEND .= $SNAP->comment_field($OUT_FORM_PREPEND);`

it calls `comment_field()`. I'm not totally sure why. But in `comment_field()` in `ext.snaptcha.php`, the `$tagdata` variable is what has the text 'Array'.

I added the following to line 203 of `ext.snaptcha.php` to convert the string 'Array' to an actual array to see what was in it:

`$tagdata = "<pre>".print_r($tagdata,true)."</pre>";`

and it appears to contain 3 values. One is the contents of my {page_body} field in my previous, closed channel entries loop. The other two are empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this seems to be a bug in DevDemon's Forms addon.

On line 730 of `mod.forms.php` it has:

`$OUT_FORM_PREPEND .= $SNAP->comment_field($OUT_FORM_PREPEND);`

Changing this to 

`$OUT_FORM_PREPEND .= $SNAP->snaptcha_field($OUT_FORM_PREPEND);`

fixes this issue.

Comment: Thanks for debugging this! Updated our internal build with the changes.